# Fix iOS keyboard for Phonegap not to dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, keyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I have been developing phonegap applications for quite sometime but i have not been able to perfectly resolve the issue where screen resizes itself and disrupts the header/footer position while dismissing the iOS keyboard. I am of the view that of we force the keyboard only to dismiss unless and until DONE button is pressed, this issue can be resolved. As i am not an ObjectiveC developer, i require some help in order to fix this keyboard in terms of cordova/phonegap using ObjC. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you want here -- can you better describe the behavior you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Actually while using phonegap, when the user dismisses the keyboard by tapping anywhere on the screen, the design of the page disrupts i.e. it shrinks itself and page header gets stucked in the middle of the screen. This issue does not occur if keyboard is dismissed using the DONE button. That's why i want to force the user to press the DONE button. Also DONE button doesn't have any keycode otherwise i could have handled it in javascript.

Comment: Care to show a screenshot? The dismissal of the keyboard via tapping vs Done shouldn't be any different (short of some event handling you might have in JS responding to touches).